# How to say to Django not to hash user passwords?

Tags: django

My user model is `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. By default it uses `PBKDF2` algorithm to encrypt passwords, so I see hashes of the passwords in the database. **Is there a way to switch off the encryption** so I could read the passwords?

I know that is not a good practice generally. I have this purpose because I encrypt passwords on Frontend level and pass the hashes through REST framework. They are supposed to be used to check signatures and to do other crypto stuff, so I need the passed passwords themselves and I don't want to create a custom user model or a related one-to-one model to store hashes in a separate field somewhere.

Django version: **3.0.5**

---

I have also tried to implement my own hasher like this:

```
# app/hashers.py

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import BasePasswordHasher


class EmptyPasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
    algorithm = 'empty'

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        """Check if the given password is correct."""
        print(password, encoded)
        return password == encoded

    def encode(self, password, salt):
        return password

    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        return {
            _('algorithm'): self.algorithm,
        }
```

And my `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    "app.hashers.EmptyPasswordHasher",
]
```

Unfortunately it didn't help. According to the source code here `https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py`, the function `check_password` calls `identify_hasher` that required the passed encoded password to have the algorithm name before `$`. Therefore the implemented `EmptyPasswordHasher` alwaws returns `False` on checks, that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you say yourself, this is a bad idea, because if someone is using the same password on your site as on another site, you are effectively risking leaking another site's password if you get hacked. It's a big responsibility.

That said, I know there might be specific cases where the above does not apply, or when you are sure that no-one is reusing their password from another site.

Django decides which method to hash a password it should use by looking at the [PASSWORD_HASHERS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS). It's possible to write your own password hash and reference that with your setting.

Hashers use the signature found in [django.hashers](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L164), so maybe you could write your own hasher that just returns the password as is?

Comment: I have just tried. It gave me the error: `return get_hashers()[0] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Edited with another approach.

Comment: Thank you. I consider the idea to write my own hasher if there's no simple way to solve my issue.

Comment: Since you will only return one of the parameters, I don't think writing this hasher will be too hard. Again, I think you should reconsider your approach because of security.

Comment: I updated my question. It looks like an empty hasher is impossible to implement in Django natively.